# Can I read the DOM of an arbitrary page from a chrome extension's content script if I don't want that page to be accessed with cookies?

Tags: javascript, web, google-chrome-extension

There is a website example.com that displays content differently depending on whether it gets the cookies or not.

In the context of my chrome extension, I want to get data extracted from the DOM of example.com but accessed without cookies.

What I've tried to do is inserting a sandboxed iframe on example.com via the extension's content script and I was hoping that since the iframe is sandbox I could access its dom from the content script.

But it doesn't seem to work as `hiddenIframe.contentDocument.body` is `null`.

Comment: You should inject a content script inside that iframe either by specifying `all_frames` in manifest.json or allFrames in chrome.scripting.executeScript.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks a lot, that's exactly what I ended up trying to do! I got the content script injected alright but how do I communicate from the iframe's content script to the host page's content script? I've tried calling `window.postMessage('iframe loaded', '*')` from the iframe's content script but the host page doesn't seem to receive it, maybe not including 'allow-same-origin' also prevents that?

Comment: Use parent.postMessage. Note that the web page can receive this message too, so to pass secrets you may want a different method.

Comment: @wOxxOm great, it's working thx! If you wanna answer the question I'll gladly accept the answer.